# Monochromatic light and interference

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction

- What I want to ask is monochromatic light necessary for interference?
- Doesn't interference occur on just the superposition of two waves(any waves)?
- And Why don't waves of different wavelengths don't interfere in a diffraction grating with  other waves but only with waves of the same wavelength(again as interference is just superposition of two waves)?
- Why do we say that the waves interfere seperately?

Answer (score 1):

Actually what's necessary for interference is a constant phase difference and nothing else.

When we have a constant phase difference the super position of the waves gives us the interference pattern but when the phase difference is not constant the superposition just averages out to give a uniform intensity.

The same frequency constraint is a consequence of the constant phase difference constraint.